# When is rawShift() reversible?

Tags: r

Can I safely assume `rawShift()` is always reversible when I shift by 1, or are there gotchas to be aware of?

Example:

```
# convert a string to raw value
starting_value <- 'here is a string'
raw_value <- charToRaw(starting_value)

# shift it, and get a new string
shift_factor <- 1
shifted_raw <- rawShift(raw_value, shift_factor)
shifted_string <- rawToChar(shifted_raw)
shifted_string
# [1] "\xd0\xca\xe4\xca@\xd2\xe6@\xc2@\xe6\xe8\xe4\xd2\xdc\xce"

# reverse the process on the new string to get the original back
rawToChar(rawShift(charToRaw(shifted_string), -shift_factor))
# [1] "here is a string"
```

If I change `shift_factor` to 2, then I no longer get the original string back. Are there any values of `starting_value` for which I won't get the original string back, assuming `shift_factor` is 1?

Comment: For those of us following, how might this shift tactic be useful, where/when might it be employed?

Comment: @Chris this type of bit shifting has many uses. It lies at the heart of file compression, cryptography (the most likely application here) and fast mathematical transforms. It's used commonly in low level languages like C, but less so in the user-facing parts of higher level languages like R, where it is often abstracted away or loses its computational virtue due to call overheads.

Comment: @AllanCameron, so the shift, by element and it's capability to be shifted could be a key, to unshift/reverse, in cryptographic sense. Great, understood. Is there as test, test pkg for this amount of elementwise shift-ability?

Comment: @Chris see me comment below the answer. You can safely shift/unshift a byte by as many leading zeros as it has. 01xxxxx can be shifted/unshifted by 1, 001xxxxx by 2, etc. 1xxxxxxx will overflow with any amount of shifting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot rely on this being reversible. It would help to show this through what happens with numbers when we use `rawShift`.

First, consider the raw number `0x01`, which is stored as a single 8-bit byte. The bits in that byte will be `00000001`. If we convert it to a number in R, we get the number 1:

```
as.numeric(as.raw(0x01))
#> [1] 1
```

When we use `rawShift`, we move all the bits to the left, so if we use a shift factor of , then `00000001` becomes `00000010`, which is the binary representation of the number 2:

```
as.numeric(rawShift(as.raw(1), 1))
#> [1] 2
```

And we could even shift it by 7 places if we want to get `10000000`, which is 128 in binary:

```r
as.numeric(rawShift(as.raw(1), 7))
#> [1] 128
```

However, if we try to left shift 8 places, this happens:

```
as.numeric(rawShift(as.raw(1), 8))
#> [1] 0
```

Our 8 bits have overflowed. The binary `1` has popped off the end, leaving all zeros. This means of course that if we try to right shift it back 8 places, we won't get back to 1, because out overflowed 1 has disappeared.

So we can fully reverse a left shift of 7 places on the value 1:

```
rawShift(rawShift(as.raw(1), 7), -7)
#> [1] 01
```

But if we try it on the number two, we will overflow and our process has become irreversible:

```
rawShift(rawShift(as.raw(2), 7), -7)
[1] 00
```

Now, it is also possible that only part of our number overflows. Suppose we have the number 3, which is `00000011` in binary and we left shift 7 places. Our first one will overflow, but the second one will move up to the first bit. When we try to reverse our shift, we get `1` instead of `3`:

```
rawShift(rawShift(as.raw(3), 7), -7)
#> [1] 01
```

Now we can consider your message. When you convert it to raw, the first character is "h". In raw this is 0x68, which is 104 in hex code. In binary it would be `01101000`. If we shift this to the left one space, nothing has overflowed and it is therefore reversible. However, if we move it left by two we get `10100000`, so when we move that back we get `00101000`, or 40, which in Ascii is `(`.

This explains why you can't safely shift raw bytes around and return the original message.

There is a way round this, which is to use the fact that numbers are stored in 64-bit precision in R, so you can safely convert to integers, left shift by as many places as you like (within reason) and be able to reverse it. For this we use `bitwShiftL` and `bitwShiftR` instead of `rawShift`. Here, I'll try to recover your message after shifting 20 bits:

```
shifted <- bitwShiftL(as.numeric(charToRaw(starting_value)), 20)
shifted
#>  [1] 109051904 105906176 119537664 105906176  33554432 110100480 120586240  33554432
#>  [9] 101711872  33554432 120586240 121634816 119537664 110100480 115343360 108003328

rawToChar(as.raw(bitwShiftR(shifted, 20)))
#> [1] "here is a string"
```

There are other ways to do this while keeping everything as an eight bit byte, using bitwise operators to make the higher bits wrap round to the lower bits, but I think this answer is already too long...

Comment: Helpful, clear answer thanks. So, in short, rawShift by 1 is not reversible when it results in binary overflow. Since basic ASCII characters (hex 0 to 127) have binary values in the 00000000 to 01111010 range, they ARE safe to shift by 1 and shift back. But if your starting string can have values from binary 10000000 and up, it's not safe. So my edge case to watch for is: unicode in source string! Thank you.

Comment: (decimal 0 to 127, i should say. hex 00 to 7F)